# How to tell this is a symmetric matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

If it given that the eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues of a matrix are orthogonal, and the eigenvalues are real, can I get the conclusion that the matrix is symmetric/self-adjoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, consider $$\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}.$$

If you add the condition that the eigenspaces sum to the entire space, the answer is...

Comment: Then, would you please help me with this problem? It is given that a 2 by 2 matrix has eigenvalues of 0 and 1, and the corresponding eigenvectors are {{1},{2}} and {{2},{-1}}. How can I tell this is a symmetric matrix? Thanks.

Comment: @Scorpio19891119: Did you read the last sentence in my answer? If the matrix has a full set of eigenvectors, which your matrix does, then the answer is yes.